# inno-setup OR javafx packager changes my desktop icon, jagged edges

Tags: javafx-2, inno-setup

So I'm using Innosetup with javafxpackager, I specify a desktop icon (.ico) in the iss file with 'SetupIconFile'.

After installing the application (Win7) the icon on the desktop has jagged edges. At first I thought something was wrong with my icon, but if I right-click the icon and change the icon to the file I specified in the iss file, it has crispy clean edges.

So I'm guessing either Inno-Setup, or javafxpackager does something to my icon (tried with all manner of sizes and multi-layered ico files btw). And I'm guessing the chances are higher it has something to do with Inno-Setup, since I specify the icon in the iss.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Edit: I said I specify the icon with 'SetupIconFile' but I didn't look correctly in my iss file, I actually do:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "MyApp\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.ico"; Check: returnTrue()
Name: "{userdesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe";  IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.ico"; Check: returnTrue()
```

Comment: The icon file you add to the setup to be installed (copied) is the icon you install (copy). Inno Setup is unable to "transform" file in the compile process (unless you are talking about embedding icon in SETUP.EXE file). In this case you should check if you add all resolutions that are used by W7 (to 256x256px).

Comment: The icon is okay, because when I manually change the icon of the installed shortcut to the same one I point to in my innosetup file, it changes to an okay one. I also tested with a multisize ico from 16x16 all the way up to 1024x1024

Comment: `SetupIconFile` only affects the icon used by the installer itself.  When you install a desktop shortcut, it will use either the `IconFilename` specified in the `[Icons]` section (which must be installed via a `[Files]` entry), or the icon of the application that the shortcut actually points to.  Inno cannot and does not modify any actual icons, it simply tells Windows to use the ones that you specified.

Comment: Or to put it another way: the problem lies with whatever you are using to generate the application .exe file.  You can work around it by setting an `IconFilename` on the shortcut in Inno, but the proper fix is to get the correct icon inside the application executable.

Comment: Ok thanks, so lets presume javafxpackager scrambles the icon. Turns out I already did what you suggested as a workaround (I edited my post), is that what you mean? Cause that doesn't work either.